# Isometry between triangle and cone

Tags: differential-geometry, isometry

In a certain exercise I have been asked to say if there is an isometry between the triangle $T =\{ z = 0, 0 < x, y, x + y < 1 \}$ and the cone $C = \{x^2 + y^2 =\frac{z^2}{4}, 0 < z < 2\}$.
I tried with a parametrization of the cone $(x,y,z) = (r\sin \theta, r \cos \theta, 2r)$. The parametrization of the plane seems much diffuclt using these coordinates, and I don't know how to continue. I would really appreciate if somebody could give me a hint of how to deal with this problem. I think that they are isometric, but I might be wrong.

Comment: There isn't even a homeomorphism between the spaces, let alone an isometry: the triangle's fundamental group is trivial (and is homeomorphic to an open disc), whereas the cone's fundamental group is not (and is homeomorphic to a punctured open disc). You could also show, more easily, that no such isometry exists by showing the diameters of the spaces are not the same.

Comment: Is there any justification without using groups? I haven't been taught about that.

Comment: As I said, if you calculate the diameters of the two spaces, you'll find that the diameters are different. Note that $\operatorname{diam} T = \sqrt{2}$, but $\operatorname{diam} C$ must be at least $2 > \sqrt{2}$, because it contains open discs of radius $1 - \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon \in (0, 1)$.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, is there any local isometry between $T$ and $C$? I tried using first fundamental form and I came out with a contradiction, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with local isometries, or differential geometry in general. I'm not the person to ask about that. Though, if a local isometry happens to be a homeomorphism, then one cannot exist (see my first comment).

Comment: I understood what you said about diameters, that was enoguh. I really appreciated that, thanks.